# How to make a JList with JLabel / JButton pairs for list items?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jlist

I want to make `JList` in Java with a list of `JLabel` and `JButton`. In each row of the list, there will be a label and a button. If I click the button, the corresponding text of the label will be displayed with the help of `JOptionPane`.

What I want to do is best described by the following image:

[image]
How can I do this?

Comment: Why have a list of labels and buttons, when you could just have a list of file names (displayed in a label) along with a label above or below the list stating *'Select file to display'*?

Comment: Can not I show a list with Label and button for each row ?

Comment: That means , You want to show two labels in each row of the list . Is it ?

Comment: No, each list item would be a single label containing one file name. If there are ten files, there would be a total of 11 labels though. One label for each file (inside the list), and one label above (or below) the entire list (outside the list) with text *Select file to display* or perhaps (longer) *Select any file below to display it*.

Comment: Yes that can be done . But  I have requirement to do like above .

Comment: Good luck with it then. I'd regard your requirement is to explain to the person that set the original requirement, the downside of being so specific. Basically controls within list cell renderers are rendered but not functional (you can render a button, but it won't act like a button). The same effect seen above can be recreated using a panels with label and button into another panel that is displayed in a scroll pane with no horizontal scroll bar. But if you want to use a `JList` component, I'd stick with 'open on select', with no separate (and effectively pointless) button.

Comment: Generally, the user would select a file name from the JList, and left click on **one** button to open the file.  This makes the list much more compact.  If you insist on multiple JButtons, I'd forget the JList and create a form using the GridBagLayout.

Comment: I also agree it is a silly requirement. Whoever gave you the requirement has no idea how to design a GUI. A JList is designed to display data not treat the data like a real component. You could use a `JTable`. At least it is designed with a renderer/editor concept so you can interact with real components. See [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

Comment: I also think it is a poor design but... couldn't you just create a JPane for each "pair" and insert a single JLabel and a single JButton in each pane, then insert all of these panes in a different, gathering Pane? I am no swing expert but JPanes are components composed of components :P